# SSRS Parse Date Error in SSRS Expression

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, ssrs-expression, datetime-parsing

Any idea why getting an #Error using the code below when the field  `fp_firstshifttimein` does not contain value. But when the field contains value, it works.

```
=IIF(IsDate(Fields!fp_firstshifttimein.Value), 
DateTime.Parse(Fields!fp_firstshifttimein.Value).addDays(8), Nothing)
```

Same issue with the code below:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!fp_firstshifttimein.Value), Nothing,
 DateTime.Parse(Fields!fp_firstshifttimein.Value).addDays(8))
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that SSRS evaluates each part of the function before the report is executed. I tried the code below. It worked.

```
=IIF(IsDate(Fields!fp_firstshifttimein.Value),
DateTime.Parse(iif(IsDate(Fields!fp_firstshifttimein.Value) ="1",
Fields!fp_firstshifttimein.Value,"01/01/1900")).addDays(8), nothing)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you have a try with this?

> `=IIF(Fields!fp_firstshifttimein.Value is nothing, nothing, 
>       DateTime.Parse(Fields!fp_firstshifttimein.Value).addDays(8))`

Answer (score 0):

Use the DateAdd function like this:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!fp_firstshifttimein.Value), Nothing,
    DateAdd("d", 8, Fields!fp_firstshifttimein.Value))
```